# jqplots scripts are not getting read in html files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqplot

I have below scripts included in my html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
.
.
</body>
</html>
```

but config,BarRenderer etc. functions are not getting identified & I am getting error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined

I identified this is due to html file not able to read those script. because if I comment all above script & run the code I get the same error.
My src path is correct. Can anyone please help me why this scripts are not being read & getting below error.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too obvious but here it goes: the jquery.min.js script is usually identified by the version number.

Could it be that it is not finding the jquery script?